# Pass data to afterClose

Tags: fancybox-3

I am using FancyBox 3  , i need to pass data to the  afterClose and trigger this data after closing the Iframe .

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="iframe"
                       data-src="{{route('tbl_properties.getApartmentsForLegal3',[$property->id,$group_id])}}"
                       href="javascript:;" type="button" class="btn btn-info " title="Show Apartments" data-reference="{{$property->property_reference}}">
                        <i class="nav-icon  i-Home-Window fa-4x "></i>
                    </a>
```

jquery :

```
    $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
        property_reference :$(this).data('reference'),


        iframe: {
            preload: false
        },
        fullScreen: {
            autoStart: true
        },
        afterClose: function(instance, slide ,property_reference)  {

            alert(property_reference);
           window.location.reload();



        }
    });
```

the data is the property_reference.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current.opts.$orig` will be reference to current trigger element (e.g., your link), and you can use that to retrieve custom data, example:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  iframe: {
    preload: false
  },
  fullScreen: {
    autoStart: true
  },
  afterClose: function(instance, current)  {

    alert(current.opts.$orig.data('reference'));

  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bPKVpB?editors=1010